# Using java.io.RandomAccessFile, how do I write a file and keep adding content to the beginning?

Tags: java, android, random-access

How do I write to a file from the beginning using RandomAccessFile?  I am writing into a file in 3mb byte chunks until it hits 100mb for benchmarking.

Comment: If it's only for benchmarking why do you need to insert at the beginning? File systems just don't work this way.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I write to a file from the beginning using RandomAccessFile?

You have to *move* the content already written.

Imagine the hard disk as a Lego base plate. 
You can start at one edge to put blocks one after the other. The blocks are the chunks of data you want to write and any consecutive line of blocks is a "file".

However, if you want to put something at the beginning of the "file" you have to take of the blocks already there, put the new block at their position and put back the new locks behind them.